# Material-ui SelectField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

there is a way to use SelectField with "required"?
I'm looking for any workaround, since I looked at the doc and [source](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/src/SelectField) on github and didn't find anything about it.

EDIT: Let me show how my code looks:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {value: null};
  }

  render(){
    const options = this.props.options.map(item => {
      return <MenuItem value={item.id} primaryText={item.name} />
    });

    return <SelectField value={this.state.value} name="role" required={true} onChange={(event, key, value) => this.setState({value: value})} >
      {options}
    </SelectField>
  }
}
```

I cannot show the code details but it's basically a component with a SelectField on it's render, a map to create the MenuItem list, a "value" on the component's state and the SelectField onChange with a arrow function calling component's setState.
I need it to be a mandatory field but, looking at the source, the SelectField doesn't seems to render a real select input and doesn't put the props on the TextField it renders.

Thanks, any help is welcome.

Comment: show us what you tried so far and what he bug looks like

Comment: I edited the question with an example (omitting code details) on how I`m using the SelectField. Hope it is helpful to figure it out.

Comment: How did you handle this? I'm stuck in a similar situation. @JonathanSilva